# How to count rows of same ID and divide that value by summed column row value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query below, I have added in the TWIN count / PlayerID. I'm getting The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

I'm trying to get the query to count the number of players ID's sum the TWIN for those aligned player ID's and divide by the amount of trips the player has. 1-6 to get the avg TWIN for each ID of the last 6 trips.

Here is what I get without trying to use the count query in the middle.

```
PlayerID    TripNumber  GamingDate  TWin
   7            1        6/1/2012    0.5
   8            1        2/28/2014  2.325
   8            2        1/29/2014   1.5
   8            3        1/26/2014   2.4
   8            4        1/24/2014   1.2
   8            5        1/19/2014   5.25
   8            6        1/15/2014  10.2294 
   9            1        12/29/2016  33.84


DECLARE
@iHostID int=NULL,
@iTrips int=6

DECLARE
@vTripcount int,
@vStartDate datetime,
@vHostID int,
@vTrips int;


SELECT 
@vHostID=@iHostID,
@vTrips=@iTrips;


SELECT
  PlayerID, 
  TripNumber,
  GamingDate,
  TWin,
  TAVG
  FROM
    (
    SELECT
    PlayerID,
    GamingDate,
    TWin,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PlayerID ORDER BY GamingDate desc) AS TripNumber
  FROM 
 (SELECT
  PlayerID,
  GamingDate,
  TWin,
  count(*) OVER (Partition by PlayerID order by GamingDate desc)/Count(*) over (partition by TWin order by GamingDate desc) as TAVG
   From

 (
     SELECT DISTINCT 
     PlayerID,
     GamingDate,
     TWin
     FROM dbo.CDS_STATDAY sd (NOLOCK) 
     WHERE IDType='P'    
  )sd

      INNER JOIN CDS_PLAYER p ON p.Player_ID=sd.PlayerID
  WHERE
      (@vHostID IS NULL OR p.HostUser_ID=@vHostID)
    )b


WHERE
  TripNumber<=@iTrips

ORDER BY
  PlayerID,
  TripNumber,
  TAVG
```

Comment: Wht is your expected result?

Comment: PlayerID    TripNumber  GamingDate  TWin
   7            1        6/1/2012    0.5
   8            1        2/28/2014  2.325
   8            2        1/29/2014   1.5
   8            3        1/26/2014   2.4
   8            4        1/24/2014   1.2
   8            5        1/19/2014   5.25
   8            6        1/15/2014  10.2294 
   9            1        12/29/2016  33.84

Comment: Sorry got pulled away. Below is what I would like to get. It took all 6 trips for ID 8 totaled twin and divided by those 6 trips. Looking at player 7 and 9 they both had 1 trip only so divided by 1 give the original twin.                                             |PlayerID  |  TWin   |
|   7           |    0.5    |
|   8           |  3.8174 |
|   9           |  33.84   |

Comment: Still not able to understand your input table... And what's your output expected results... Can you please modify the question and add these details?

Comment: I'm trying lol. I can't get it to table format.

Comment: PlayerID    TWin
   7               0.5
   8             3.8174
   9             33.84

Comment: This is incredible lol...first day on stack....how do I insert a table....tried the help and It isn't formatting

Comment: +----------+----------------+--+--+
| PlayerID |      TWin      |  |  |
+----------+----------------+--+--+
|        7 | 0.5            |  |  |
|        8 | 3.8174         |  |  |
|        9 | 33.84          |  |  |
+----------+----------------+--+--+

Answer (score 1):

You could get your result using the SUM and COUNT functions

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (PlayerId INT, TripNumber INT, GamingDate DATE, TWin DECIMAL(18,4))
INSERT INTO @T VALUES 
(7,1,'20120106',0.5),
(8,1,'20140228',2.325),
(8,2,'20140129',1.5),
(8,3,'20140126',2.4),
(8,4,'20140124',1.2),
(8,5,'20140119',5.25),
(8,6,'20140115',10.2294),
(9,1,'20161229',33.84)

SELECT PlayerId, SUM(TWIN) / COUNT(PlayerID) AS result
FROM @T
GROUP BY PlayerId

+---------+----------+
|PlayerId |result    |
+---------+----------+
|7        |0.500000  |
|8        |3.817400  |
|9        |33.840000 |
+---------+----------+
```

Comment: It's for 200 thousand rows though.. probably should have mentioned that.

Comment: @nmoore: this will still work, see what the performance is. Maybe compare it when you create a nonclustered index on the playerid column.

Comment: excuse my lack of knowledge. I was just thrown into a sql ocean and am trying to learn as fast as possible. If I do it this way I would need to hard code all of those values after 'insert into@t values' for nearly 200k rows? or is that just showing what values would be inserted? also could I just drop this table and still get desired results at the tail end of the query?

Comment: I used a table variable just to have test data for my query. This you can skip. Just place my logic around your query, and place your query in a subquery

Comment: so I'm trying. here is where I put it  | SELECT
  PlayerID, 
  TripNumber,
  GamingDate,
  SUM(TWin) / Count(PlayerID) as TAVG
  FROM
   | (
    SELECT
    PlayerID,
    GamingDate,
    TWin,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PlayerID ORDER BY GamingDate desc) AS TripNumber |

Comment: Sorry that is hard to read I can't get the formatting correct for comments but I placed the group by down at the bottom of the query and it tells me that b.tripnumber, b.gamingdate need agregated

Comment: What do you want in your final result? You are now talking about gamingdate and tripnumber, but since you are aggregating you need an aggregation function on those columns too.